# Start Riak crashing after 30 seconds

Tags: solr, crash, erlang, riak, leveldb

`$ riak start` crashing after 30 seconds of its start. I'm having following (changes) settings in my `riak.conf`:

```
search = on
storage_backend = leveldb
riak_control = on
```

`crash.log` contains the following:

```
2016-06-30 14:49:38 =ERROR REPORT====
** Generic server yz_solr_proc terminating 
** Last message in was {check_solr,0}
** When Server state == {state,"./data/yz",#Port<0.9441>,8093,8985}
** Reason for termination == 
** "solr didn't start in alloted time"
2016-06-30 14:49:38 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: yz_solr_proc:init/1
    pid: <0.582.0>
    registered_name: yz_solr_proc
    exception exit: {"solr didn't start in alloted time",[{gen_server,terminate,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,744}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
    ancestors: [yz_solr_sup,yz_sup,<0.578.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',#Port<0.9441>,normal}]
    links: [<0.580.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 376
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 16170
  neighbours:
2016-06-30 14:49:38 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,yz_solr_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     "solr didn't start in alloted time"
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.582.0>},{name,yz_solr_proc},{mfargs,{yz_solr_proc,start_link,["./data/yz","./data/yz_temp",8093,8985]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,5000},{child_type,worker}]

2016-06-30 14:49:39 =ERROR REPORT====
** Generic server yz_solr_proc terminating 
** Last message in was {#Port<0.12204>,{exit_status,1}}
** When Server state == {state,"./data/yz",#Port<0.12204>,8093,8985}
** Reason for termination == 
** {"solr OS process exited",1}
2016-06-30 14:49:39 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: yz_solr_proc:init/1
    pid: <0.7631.0>
    registered_name: yz_solr_proc
    exception exit: {{"solr OS process exited",1},[{gen_server,terminate,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,744}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
    ancestors: [yz_solr_sup,yz_sup,<0.578.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',#Port<0.12204>,normal}]
    links: [<0.580.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 1598
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 8968
  neighbours:
2016-06-30 14:49:39 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,yz_solr_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {"solr OS process exited",1}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.7631.0>},{name,yz_solr_proc},{mfargs,{yz_solr_proc,start_link,["./data/yz","./data/yz_temp",8093,8985]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,5000},{child_type,worker}]

2016-06-30 14:49:39 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,yz_solr_sup}
     Context:    shutdown
     Reason:     reached_max_restart_intensity
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.7631.0>},{name,yz_solr_proc},{mfargs,{yz_solr_proc,start_link,["./data/yz","./data/yz_temp",8093,8985]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,5000},{child_type,worker}]

2016-06-30 14:49:39 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,yz_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     shutdown
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.580.0>},{name,yz_solr_sup},{mfargs,{yz_solr_sup,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,5000},{child_type,supervisor}]

2016-06-30 14:49:39 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,yz_sup}
     Context:    shutdown
     Reason:     reached_max_restart_intensity
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.580.0>},{name,yz_solr_sup},{mfargs,{yz_solr_sup,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,5000},{child_type,supervisor}]
```

Comment: Which version of Riak are you using? Do you see anything in /var/log/riak/solr.log?

Comment: I'm using Riak KV 2.1.4

Comment: Do you have a solr.log on your system? Check if for exceptions and error messages, it looks like the JVM crashes for some reason.

Comment: solr.log 
2016-07-01 12:13:33,697 [DEBUG] <qtp1340328248-194>@HttpParser.java:281 filled 106/106
2016-07-01 12:13:33,697 [DEBUG] <qtp1340328248-194 - /internal_solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&wt=json>@Server.java:363 REQUEST /internal_solr/admin/cores on BlockingHttpConnection@2b406e05,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=1,c=0},r=27682
2016-07-01 12:13:33,697 [DEBUG] <qtp1340328248-194 - /internal_solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&wt=json>@ContextHandler.java:931 scope null||/internal_solr/admin/cores @

Comment: The solr.log seems clipped, and from a different date. It could help if you added it in full or at least its tail to the question.

Comment: Finally fixed that issue. Cause /etc/hosts file did't have local ip mapping as follows(`/etc/hosts`): 
`127.0.0.1 localhost` This localhost and ip used solr as default host so after added that mapping into /etc/hosts file it resolved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the ports used by Solr are available. The defaults are 8093 for search, and 8985 for JMX.
2. Tune your system to improve performance. Follow [Improving Performance for Linux](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/performance/).
3. In `riak.conf`, increase the JVM's heap size, the default of 1G is often not enough. For example, `search.solr.jvm_options=-d64 -Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:+UseStringCache -XX:+UseCompressedOops` (see [Search Settings](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/configuring/search/#jvm-installation)).
4. On a slow machine, Solr just may take longer to start. Try increasing `search.solr.start_timeout`.

Solr directories must be writable (usually `/var/lib/riak/data/yz*`), and a compatible JVM be used.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't helped me.

Comment: @MasudurRahman post the trailing part of your solr.log please, search for ERROR and FATAL.

Comment: 2016-07-04 22:48:43,518 [INFO] <qtp1340328248-54 - /internal_solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&wt=json>@LoggingInfoStream.java:34 [IW][qtp1340328248-54 - /internal_solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&wt=json]: nrtIsCurrent: infoVersion matches: true; DW changes: false; BD changes: false
2016-07-04 22:48:43,518 [INFO] <qtp1340328248-54 - /internal_solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&wt=json>@LoggingInfoStream.java:34 [DW][qtp1340328248-54 - /internal_solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&wt=json]: anyChanges? numDocsInRam=0 deletes=false hasTickets:false pendingChangesInFullFlush: false

Comment: This chunk of solr.log doesn't help. There must be some `ERROR` or `FATAL` that prevents Solr from starting. BTW, how many Riak nodes, and with what `n_val` are you running? It is pretty common for people who just get started with Riak to run a single node without tuning the ring size and replication accordingly. Has your Riak ever started normally? Is there any data in it?

Comment: Anyway, finally fixed that issue. Cause  file did't have local ip mapping as follows(`/etc/hosts`):

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

This localhost and ip used solr as default host so after added that mapping into /etc/hosts file it resolved my issue.
Thanks

Comment: Great! You might want to add this info as an answer or an update to your original question so that others could benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Riak**'s internal **solr** use `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` as default host. So it should have defined in `/etc/hosts` file:

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

FYI, if you use windows your hosts file location could be different.